# How to put an array in an array using a foreach (instagram api) PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I haven't finished the code yet, but I want to get all the values of `$pictures` in an array called "data". So there are  arrays pictures with specific information in an array "data". Then encode it to JSON.

```
function jSONEncode($data){

    foreach ($data->data as $key){
        $url = $key->images->thumbnail->url;
        $longitude = $key->location->longitude;
        $latitude = $key->location->longitude;

        $pictures = array(
            "url" => $url,
            "latitude" => $longitude,
            "longitude" => $latitude,
            "name" => "bla bla"

        );
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

```
$json['data'] = array();
foreach ($data->data as $key){
    $url = $key->images->thumbnail->url;
    $longitude = $key->location->longitude;
    $latitude = $key->location->longitude;

    $pictures = array(
        "url" => $url,
        "latitude" => $longitude,
        "longitude" => $latitude,
        "name" => "bla bla"

    );

    $json['data'][] = $pictures;
};

echo json_encode($json);
exit;
```

Now, you can access in javascript by using json.data